# Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDF_reciept::FPDF() in C:\wamp\www\pdf\cr.php on line 8

Tags: php, fpdf

Can you pleas help me with this code....

```
<?php
    require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

    class PDF_reciept extends FPDF
    {
        function __construct($orientation = 'P', $unit = 'pt', $format = 'Letter', $margin = 40)
        {
            $this->FPDF($orientation, $unit, $format);
            $this->SetTopMargin($margin);
            $this->SetLeftMargin($margin);
            $this->SetRightMargin($margin);
            $this->SetAutoPageBreak(true, $margin);
        }

        function Header()
        {
            $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 20);
            $this->SetFillColor(36, 96, 84);
            $this->SetTextColor(225);
            $this->Cell(0, 30, "Nettuts+ Online Store", 0, 1, 'C', true);
        }

        function Footer()
        {
            $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
            $this->SetTextColor(0);
            $this->XY(40, -60);
            $this->Cell(0, 20, "Thank you for shopping at Nettuts+", 'T', 0, 'C');
        }
    }

    $pdf = new PDF_reciept();

    $pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: There is an issue at line 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding the constructor, so you have to call parent constructor with expected signature, like `parent::__construct();` on top of your constructor function:

```
public function __construct($orientation = 'P', $unit = 'pt', $format = 'Letter', $margin = 40)
{
    parent::__construct($orientation, $unit, $format, $margin);
    //$this->FPDF($orientation, $unit, $format);
    $this->SetTopMargin($margin);
    $this->SetLeftMargin($margin);
    $this->SetRightMargin($margin);
    $this->SetAutoPageBreak(true, $margin);
}
```

Also all functions within your class should be declared with access modifier (public, private etc.)

Comment: Great, mark the answer then in order to close the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDF_reciept::FPDF() in C:\wamp\www\pdf\cr.php on line 8`
says that you try to access `PDF_reciept::FPDF()` method, but you do not have such method in your class.

Answer (score 0):

please check if you have the $this->FPDF($orientation, $unit, $format); function defined in fpdf/fpdf.php.

or if you want to call parent FPDF constructor, then use parent::__construct($orientation, $unit, $format, $margin);